# Does Fitbit Flex Count Indoor Rowing Machine Strokes

Tags: exercise, tracking, fitbit

I am thinking of purchasing a Fitbit Flex. I have an indoor rowing machine which is my main form of exercise other than walking. I can't do much else because of injuries. I wondered if my rowing strokes will be counted and recorded. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronics.

Comment: Related to: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/active-minutes-on-flex?rq=1

Comment: Not really!! It will count some "strokes" I have a fit bit one.....If I row for 30 min, I think I get around 1000 steps

Comment: What type of rowing machine?

Comment: Are you trying to record rowing strokes, or, somehow convert that into some other number?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Fitbit site and a number of [reviews](http://techandnonsense.com/fitbit-flex-review/), the Flex measure / keeps track of:

- Steps taken
- Distance traveled
- Calories Burned
- Active Minutes
- Hours Slept
- Quality of Sleep

but per the review, not strokes rowed. Your only real option to accurately record your stroke count is to upgrade the rowing machine to one that includes a Bluetooth based stroke tracker.

Answer (score -2):

The fitbit flex counts steps and afaik it can only measure your heartbeat rate when you actively decide to measure it (i.e. it will not measure it passively), also, it's very unreliable at higher rates and when moving around.

In essence, the Fitbit flex, and all similar devices, suck, they're overpriced pedometers.

Most phones can function as pedometers today so I'd go with that instead. My Samsung Galaxy 5 measures all my steps during the day.

What's your goal with rowing?

Comment: The Flex has no ability to measure heart rate.